# add "#"on crontab line

Tags: text-processing, sed, command-line

I need to change a line on crontab with a linux command.
I can't find solutions with the sed command. You can help me?
The original line is:

```
* * * * * root /foo/pluto/minnie.sh
```

and must become

```
#* * * * * root /foo/pluto/minnie.sh
```

A thousand thanks

Richard

Comment: I suggest to [edit] your question and add the `sed` command(s) you tried and the resulting output. Maybe ssomeone can help to fix possible errors instead of proposing a totally different solution. Showing a few more lines of the `crontab` file would help to verify that no wrong line is modified by a proposed solution.

Comment: Can we assume that the crontab is otherwise empty? If not, what tells this entry apart from other entries? If this is the only entry, would _deleting_ the crontab be an option?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi -le '$_ = "#$@" if $_ eq "* * * * * root /foo/pluto/minnie.sh"' your-file
```

Is one option for an exact match of the contents of the line.

You can also store the line in a variable:

```
line='* * * * * root /foo/pluto/minnie.sh'
```

and then use it as:

```
file=some-file
perl -pi -lse '$_ = "#$_" if $_ -eq $line' -- -line="$line" -- "$file"
```

Or pass as an environment variable:

```
export LINE='* * * * * root /foo/pluto/minnie.sh'
perl -pi -le '$_ = "#$_" if $_ -eq $ENV{LINE}' -- "$file"
```

To integrate that with `crontab -e`:

```
LINE='* * * * * root /foo/pluto/minnie.sh' \
VISUAL='perl -pi -le '\''$_ = "#$_" if $_ -eq $ENV{LINE}
  '\'' --' crontab -e
```

Or:

```
LINE='* * * * * root /foo/pluto/minnie.sh' \
  CODE='$_ = "#$_" if $_ -eq $ENV{LINE}' \
  VISUAL='perl -pi -le "$CODE" --' crontab -e
```

Then `crontab` will run `sh` with the contents of `$VISUAL` a space and the name of a temp file as code for it to interpret, and both `sh` and `perl` will find the variables they need (`CODE` for `sh`, `LINE` for `perl`) in their environment.

---

<sup>¹  it's clearly not a *visual* editor we're using here but `$VISUAL` has precedence over `$EDITOR`, so we'd have to unset `$VISUAL` if we used `$EDITOR`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
crontab -l |sed 's/\(.*minnie\)/#\1/' > tmpfile
crontab tmpfile
rm tmpfile
```

or

```
EDITOR=/usr/bin/ed crontab -e
1
/minnie
s/^/#/
w
q
```

Comment: I've used the second option (or variants of it) for years. It is reliable although you might want to test the `ed` commands on a dummy file first.

Comment: Note that the format of the crontab shown in the question suggests that it's not someone's personal crontab, but a system crontab entry. It would therefore not be managed by the `crontab` command.

Comment: @Kusalananda I missed that.  But in that case very easy `sed` or `awk` command on `/etc/crontab` or `/etc/crontab*/*` (fill in the exact name) would be possible.

Comment: The `ed` script can be reduced to `1;/minnie/s/^/#/` followed by `w` and `q` (or `wq`, if supported).

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find solutions with the sed command

It is quite simple: to address a group of lines you can specify a rule. A rule consists of a regexp to select the lines and a group of commands to be run on these lines. Here is an example:

```
sed '/^abc/ {; s/abc/xyz/g; }' /path/to/input > output
```

This works only on the lines starting with "abc". In all these lines (only in these) any string "abc" is changed to "xyz".

So, if you want to comment lines replace the beginning of the line with an octothorpe:

```
sed '/minnie/ {; s/^/# / ; }' /path/to/input > output
```

If you want to add a new line after the one commented out that is possible too with the "a"-command:

```
sed '/minnie/ {
                s/^/# /
                a\
this gets inserted after the commented line
              }' /path/to/input > output
```

Finally: sed writes its output to `stdout` per default. You can't immediately pipe it back into the original file, because that would corrupt it. Also, stay away from abominations like the "-i"-switch i.e. GNU-sed has, because it is non-POSIX and will make your scripts less portable. Do it like this, which is safer and better anyways:

```
if sed '<your sed-script>' input > output ; then
     mv output input
else
     print -u2 - "sed malfunction, check output"
     exit 1
fi
```